# System.OutOfMemoryException in use Dictionary<TKey, TValue>

Tags: c#

I'm getting error message:

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

when trying:

```
try
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= Int32.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        dict.Add(i, i);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

It's dumping my system about 30s.

My system:

[image: 1]

My question: To store `2147483647 + 1 = 2147483648` elements (and do nothing), does .Net require more than 2Gb RAM? Is it expensive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read this article:

[“Out Of Memory” Does Not Refer to Physical Memory](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory/)

An [OutOfMemoryException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception(v=vs.110).aspx) exception has two major causes:

> You are attempting to expand a StringBuilder object beyond the length
>   defined by its StringBuilder.MaxCapacity property.
>
> The common language runtime cannot allocate enough contiguous memory
>   to successfully perform an operation. This exception can be thrown by
>   any property assignment or method call that requires a memory
>   allocation. For more information on the cause of the
>   OutOfMemoryException exception, see "Out of Memory" Does Not Refer to
>   Physical Memory.
>
> This type of OutOfMemoryException exception represents a catastrophic
>   failure. If you choose to handle the exception, you should include a
>   catch block that calls the Environment.FailFast method to terminate
>   your app and add an entry to the system event log, as the following
>   example does.